# How to build a word-cloud / tag-cloud using tailwind css in Next.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have following data structure. Where for each tag we have the amount of times the tag was used in blogposts.

```js
tags = {
    go: 12,
    html: 6,
    js: 9,
    .....
}
```

Currently I was thinking about following map function to build the tag cloud.

```js
export default function TagCloud({ tags }) {
  const tagCount = Object.keys(tags).length;
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap content-around items-center align-middle w-full">
      {Object.entries(tags).map((t) => {
        const slug = t[0].toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-").replace("/", "-");

        return (
          <Link key={slug} href={`/blog/tags/${slug}`}>
            <a
              className={cn("p-1 mx-1 hover:underline hover:text-gray-600", {
                "text-xs": t[1],
                "text-sm": t[1],
                "text-base": t[1],
                "text-lg": t[1],
                "text-xl": t[1],
                "text-2xl": t[1],
                "text-3xl": t[1],
              })}
            >
              {t[0]}
            </a>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using `t[1]` combined with the `tagCount` and probably some other values we need to capture before the map we should then be able to define the `tailwind-css` classname to define the font-size. However I'm stuck in my thought process on the formula to define which classname to use.

Secondly depending on the amount of times a tag is used and how many different tags are used we might also require more or less variations in the tag sizing as I currently put in the code. I thought using the classnames library this would be easiest to define if a tag should get a certain classname.

Am I oversimplifying what I try to achieve?